# Is Wikipedia geocoding API deprecated/down?

Tags: wikipedia-api, reverse-geocoding, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I've been playing around with the Wikipedia reverse geocoding API listed at:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData

The specific API request I make is of the type:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=37.786971|-122.399677&format=json](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gscoord=37.786971%7C-122.399677&format=json)

The API worked great in the past. Today, somehow, the API returns an empty JSON object. Is the API deprecated or down? I can't seem to find any details on the page or the API help page or the MediaWiki page.

If deprecated, is there any alternative I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it was just a temporary stop: https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72559#c4